# Filtering postgres value based on certain criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql table on postgres 11 where I have a column of people and a column of their preferred airlines.

```
Name | Airlines
----------------
Patrick | Delta
Patrick | United
Patrick | American
James   | Delta
Sophie  | United
Sophie  | American
John    | United
```

I need to have the values in a table where if someone has Delta in their preferred airlines, then they have Delta, otherwise they get Other-Airlines like this, *desired result*:

```
Name | Airlines
----------------
Patrick | Delta
James   | Delta
Sophie  | Other-Airlines
John    | Other-Airlines.
```

Is there a way to filter this out easily ? I know with numerical or alphabetical values it's easy to use min, max, or something to that effect.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by`:

```
select name,
       (case when count(*) filter (airline = 'Delta') > 0
             then 'Delta' else 'Other airline'
        end) as preferred
from t
group by name;
```

You can also use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (name) name,
       (case when airline = 'Delta' then airline else 'Other airline'
        end) as preferred
from t
order by name, (airline = 'Delta') desc
```